# Impossible to get the variable with subscribing to an Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I posted a question yesterday about an iteration loop that I could not create.
I thought my problem was solved, when I subscribe to this function I can not get the variable.

Here is my function:

```
getThreadFromSubscription(threadId: string): Observable<Thread> {
return this.threads.map((threadDictionary: { [key: string]: Thread }) 
  => {
  for (let key in threadDictionary) {
    if (threadDictionary[key].id == threadId)
      return threadDictionary[key];
  }
});
}
```

And here the function where I subscribe to the flow:

```
addNewMessage(objMessage: any) : void {

  this.getThreadFromSubscription(objMessage.id)
    .subscribe ((thread: Thread) => {
    if(thread!= null) {
      objMessage.thread = thread;
    }
    });
    if (objMessage.thread != null) {
     const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);
     this.addMessage(newMessage);
   }
   else {
     const newThread: Thread = new Thread(objMessage.id, 
       objMessage.name);
     this.addThread(newThread);
     objMessage.thread = newThread;
     const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);
     this.addMessage(newMessage);
   }
}
```

When I test the variable objMessage.thread out of the .subscribe loop, it is undefined.

I think the first function works 'getThreadFromSubscription'.
But when I subscribe to this stream, my 'objMessage.thread' does not retain its initialization (objMessage.thread = thread).

I do not see why. I use the v4 of Angular.

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
UPDATE

When I tried your first solution :

```
addNewMessage(objMessage: any) : void {
this.getThreadFromSubscription(objMessage.id).
  .subscribe ((thread: Thread) => {
  if(thread!= null) {
    objMessage.thread = thread;
  }

  if (objMessage.thread != null) {
      const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);
      this.addMessage(newMessage);
    }
    else {
      const newThread: Thread = new Thread(objMessage.id, objMessage.name);
      this.addThread(newThread);
      objMessage.thread = newThread;
      const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);
      this.addMessage(newMessage);
    }
  });
 }

getThreadFromSubscription(threadId: string): Observable<Thread> {
return this.threads.map((threadDictionary: { [key: string]: Thread }) 
=> {
  for (let key in threadDictionary) {
    if (threadDictionary[key].id == threadId)
      return threadDictionary[key];
  }
 });
 }
```

I have this error :

```
 Unhandled Promise rejection: Maximum call stack size exceeded ; Zone: 
 <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: RangeError: Maximum call stack 
 size exceeded
```

And for the second solution :

```
addNewMessage(objMessage: any) : void {
this.getThreadFromSubscription(objMessage.id).take(1)
  .subscribe ((thread: Thread) => {
  if(thread!= null) {
    objMessage.thread = thread;
  }
  });

  if (objMessage.thread != null) {
      const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);
      this.addMessage(newMessage);
    }
    else {
      const newThread: Thread = new Thread(objMessage.id, objMessage.name);
      this.addThread(newThread);
      objMessage.thread = newThread;
      const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);
      this.addMessage(newMessage);
    }
  }

getThreadFromSubscription(threadId: string): Observable<Thread> {
   return this.threads.map((threadDictionary: { [key: string]: Thread 
 }) => {
  for (let key in threadDictionary) {
    if (threadDictionary[key].id == threadId)
      return threadDictionary[key];
  }
  });
 }
```

It doesn't work. My variable 'objMessage.thread' is undefined.

Comment: Ah my bad, this is a different question right?

Comment: Yes it's in the same project, but it's a different question ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are expecting the `subscribe` block to execute synchronously, however, this is not the case. You should move the `if-else` block inside the subscribe method like so:

```js
this.getThreadFromSubscription(objMessage.id)
    .subscribe ((thread: Thread) => {
        if(thread!= null) {
            objMessage.thread = thread;
        }

        if (objMessage.thread != null) {
            const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);
            this.addMessage(newMessage);
        } else {
            const newThread: Thread = new Thread(objMessage.id, objMessage.name);
            this.addThread(newThread);
            objMessage.thread = newThread;
            const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);
            this.addMessage(newMessage);
        }
});
```

Alternatively, you can force the `Observable` to behave synchronously by using the [`take`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/take.md) operator like so:

```js
this.getThreadFromSubscription(objMessage.id).take(1)
    .subscribe ((thread: Thread) => {
        if(thread!= null) {
            objMessage.thread = thread;
        }
    });

// Rest of your code
```

Comment: I do not understand why but these two solutions don't work. I have edited my post.

Comment: You don't have a `thread` variable defined anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: I modified my post because I was wrong for the first solution.
The 'thread' variable is retrieved by subscribe.

Comment: Do you know why it returns 6 values ​​to objMessage.thread?
How to make it run only once the loop subscribe?

Comment: How many `threads` are there in the class that has the `getThreadFromSubscription` method? I bet there are 6. `map` just modifies the return value at each index of the `threads` array. You most likely want to use a filter and take the first value.

Comment: Should I create this filter in my loop this.threads.map or in the .subscribe loop?
Sorry I do not think I understand

Comment: ```this.threads.filter((threadDictionary: { [key: string]: Thread })  => {
        return Object.keys(threadDictionary).some((key) => threadDictionary[key].id == threadId);
    }).map((threadDictionary: { [key: string]: Thread }) => {
          for (let key in threadDictionary) {
    if (threadDictionary[key].id == threadId)
      return threadDictionary[key];
  }
}).first();```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works :) I will never have done it all alone! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your function getThreadFromSubscription() need to return an observable, so change its return statement to this:

```
 return Observable.of(threadDictionary[key]);
```

Comment: But I think threadDictionary[key] it's an Observable : (Observable<Thread>)